Even after changing Default Behaviour Mode to 3D, my scene still remains in 2D. Why?

I had created a new scene, which didn't have sky and directional light.

To solve this, I created a new skybox, then added to the maincamera. But there was no difference to scene & game view. 

Then I realised that the main issue might be the 2D/3D setting, not the skybox.

I went to 'Edit > Project Settings > Default Behaviour Mode > 3D' But there was no difference to scene & game view. (Even after quitting and reopening it, there's no change)
This scene is Basic URP.



I want to work in a 3D environment that has a sky and a directional light. What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

Does this answer your question? 3D vs 2D mode only changes the default settings used when importing images or creating a new scene. Toggling this setting will not retroactively alter the contents of a scene you've already created.

Then what is causing the scene to not have a sky and directional light? I have the same problem when I create a new scene. I am so stuck...

You already posted a question about that. You do not need to post another question about the same topic to guess at a potential answer.

Your scene looks like 3D to me. Can you rotate the directional right 360 degrees on each of the following axis: X, Y, and Z (separately - one axis at a time - 360 degrees for each axis) ? Sometime, the directional light does not point toward the objects, and so, the object does not light up.

Also, (1) Make sure the light color is WHITE or Yellow, and NOT BLACK. (2) Increase the intensity of the light to 2 to see if it works.

Have you read Unity tutorial on how to create and add a skybox to a scene ? Here is the link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/skyboxes-using.html#:~:text=From%20the%20menu%20bar%2C%20click,to%20set%20up%20the%20skybox.

Does this answer your question? Unity scene doesn't have skybox and lightsource
